# Put editText in AlertDialog without custom view?

Tags: android, view, android-alertdialog

Is their a better way to put a EditText in a alertDialog, instead of using a custom view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
final EditText input = new EditText(this);

    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Title");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Message");
    alertDialog.setView(input, 10, 0, 10, 0); // 10 spacing, left and right
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Clicked
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
```

If you want to add a custom Layout for your editText the only option i know is:
inflate your layout  with a LayoutInflater, and use that as the View.

Comment: Sweet that works! Except for the padding, I have been using LayoutInfalter for my custom views, so I was just curious if their was a better way!

Comment: accept the answer, if this is what you are looking for!! thanks

for the padding im gonna try it for you, normaly that should work

Comment: The padding might be my fault, since I changed the code around a little bit!